# Golang, use case with pointer and interface

Tags: go

I am writing a library I'll need to use in others parts of my programs, for this I had to use a lot interfaces and I ended up in a case I don't know how to solve.

Here is my code :

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "test/bar"
)

// Foo is defined in another package
type Foo struct {
    WhatWeWant string
}

func (f *Foo) getResult() interface{} {
    return f.WhatWeWant
}

func newFoo() interface{} {
    return &Foo{
        WhatWeWant: "test",
    }
}

func main() {
    bar := bar.Bar{
        NewFooer: newFoo,
    }
    bar.Execute()
}
```

bar/bar.go

```
package bar

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type myInterface interface {
    getResult() interface{}
}

type Bar struct {
    NewFooer func() interface{}
}

func (b *Bar) Execute() {
    foo := b.NewFooer()

    // executeLib only accept pointer
    executeLibWrapper(foo)

    whatWeWant := foo.(myInterface).getResult()
    fmt.Println(whatWeWant)
    fmt.Println("Win!")

}

// This function is executed in an external library I have no control on
func executeLibWrapper(src interface{}) {
    executeLib(reflect.TypeOf(src))
}

func executeLib(src reflect.Type) {

    if src.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        executeLib(src.Elem())
        return
    }

    switch src.Kind() {
    case reflect.Struct:
        fmt.Println("Struct OK!")
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Can't detect struct, we detect %s", src.Kind()))
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
panic: interface conversion: *main.Foo is not bar.myInterface: missing method getResult
```

My goal is to be able to call getResult() after executing the library.
Here is a playground : https://play.golang.org/p/7G2wc6uGngH. This playground works, so there is a strong possibilities that the problem come from the fact it is in different packages.

Note that I need to pass a pointer to executeLib, I can't get the pointer in execute() because otherwise I'll lose the foo type and can't execute the library : https://play.golang.org/p/A8ETfuMQyQB. This is why I have to return the pointer in newFoo()

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I updated my question with a project example, since the playground was not enough to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share an interface and their funcs across packages you have export the interface and its funcs:

```
type MyInterface interface {
    GetResult() interface{}
}
```

When you change the implementation of Foo

```
func (f *Foo) GetResult() interface{} {
    return f.WhatWeWant
}
```

and the call

```
whatWeWant := foo.(MyInterface).GetResult()
```

it compiles and executes without panic.

Comment: Exact! Can't believe I missed something so obvious. Guess I spent all my energy understanding the troubles with the external lib. Thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

Got the result [here](https://play.golang.org/p/BCo_oURJwJb). Hope this can help.

Seems the trick is using these. Adding these snippet introduces the smallest impact on code.

Just make `NewFooer` a member function of `Bar`. When `NewFooer` is invoked `newFoo` is called.

```
func (m *Bar) NewFooer() interface{} {
    return newFoo()
}
```

Eventually this snippet is invoked as well

```
func newFoo() interface{} {
    return &Foo{
        WhatWeWant: "test",
    }
}
```